# JAWS is not identifying buttons or reading button text

Tags: google-chrome, button, jaws-screen-reader

I am using buttons in my application , but on pressing b or insert b, JAWS is not identifying the buttons and saying "no buttons were found".
When I manually tabover to the button, button text is not read.
I am using JAWS 2022 on chrome.

```
<button class="btn btn-secondary" id="search" type="button">
                    Search
                </button>
```

or

```
<button id="skip" onclick="skipToMain()" >Skip to content</button>
```

Can someone help in identifying what is the issue here?Is some attribute missing or JAWS setting needs to be changed?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Buttons work great for me with JAWS and NVDA.  There must be additional code you are not sharing that is causing the problem.  If the button text is not read, it sounds like you might have `aria-hidden="true"` set on a containing element.

Comment: Same issue for me. NVDA reads the page correctly, but JAWS says no links? I can see the buttons and they have aria-labels